# How to pass yes to sh command like curl URL.sh | sh

Tags: bash

I'm trying to install starship by a single command but when I run the following one it asks key input. Then how can I pass it "y" automatically without typing? I believe `yes` command may help but don't know how can I use in this case.

```bash
$ curl -sS https://starship.rs/install.sh | sh

  Configuration
> Bin directory: /usr/local/bin
> Platform:      unknown-linux-musl
> Arch:          aarch64

> Tarball URL: https://github.com/starship/starship/releases/latest/download/starship-aarch64-unknown-linux-musl.tar.gz
? Install Starship latest to /usr/local/bin? [y/N]
```

Comment: '- y' , should work

Comment: @MurtazaHussain May I ask where should I put it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't, because you are already redirecting `curl` to `sh`.

Inspecting the script reveals that you can run it with `-y` to avoid interactive prompts, so probably just do that.

```
curl -sS https://starship.rs/install.sh | sh -s -- -y
```

The `-s` option allows you to pass options to the script from the `sh` command line and the `--` is then required to separate the `sh` options from the options you pass to the script.

In the general case, if the script was written so that it unconditionally requires interactive I/O, you really need to download it to a file and then run that file with redirection.

```
#!/bin/bash
dest=$(mktemp -t) || exit
trap 'rm -f "$dest"' ERR EXIT  HUP INT TERM
curl -sS https://starship.rs/install.sh >"$dest"
yes | sh "$dest"
```

The use of `ERR` and `EXIT` with `trap` is a Bash extension. If you informally run this by hand, the scripted generation of a temporary file and the associated trap can probably be replaced with something more ad-hoc.